# Fermats equation in java

Tags: java, math, recursion

I am trying to make an recursive analysis program with fermat's last equation, but it keeps returning that the equation is wrong I don't understand?

```
public class fermatdata 
{
    public static void data(int a, int b, int c, int n)
    {
        if ((Math.pow(a, n)) + (Math.pow(b, n)) == (Math.pow(c, n)))
        {   
            System.out.println("Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!");
            return;             
        }
        else
        {               
            data(a-1, b-1, c-1, n-1);
            if (n < 2)
            {                   
                return;                 
            }
            else
            {                   
                data(a-1, b-1, c-1, n-1);                   
            }               
        }
        System.out.println("No, that doesn't work. Fermat was right");          
    }       
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Fermat's last theorem stated that the formula a^n + b^n = c^n while n>2 and all of the numbers are integers will never be correct. Here I am going to do an analysis with all the numbers starting at 100,000 and count backwords to 3");
        data(100000, 100000, 100000, 100000);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: You first recur, then check `n < 2`. It's dead code, basically.

Comment: Be aware of double comparison `if ((Math.pow(a, n)) + (Math.pow(b, n)) == (Math.pow(c, n)))` you should not compare `float/double` with `==`

Comment: How is that dead code? It just stops running the code if n is less than 2 and I start it at 100,000 so shouldn't it run all 999,997 numbers first?

Comment: so I should cast those exponents to an integer?

Comment: Just think about it for a second. It's pure logic.

Comment: What error, or unexpected result, are you getting?

Comment: @vikingsteve It says "Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik When I put `&& n>2` in the original if statement it has the same result...

Comment: Yes, well there are many issues with your code; one at a time. Another: you fail to check all *combinations* of a,b,c,n. You just decrement them all at once.

Comment: Pretty silly to be using int when you could use long; pretty silly to use long when you could use BigNumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the first line like this:

```
        data(a-1, b-1, c-1, n-1);
```

Ok, now see what Math.pow(100000,100000) gives (Infinity). I think the problem is that you are using values that are too high (at least for n).

Comment: No change it still says what it did before

Comment: Ha ha, so he has Infinity + Infinity == Infinity. Yes, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the powers you are using lead to 'Infinity' because the numbers are too big.

Since 'Infinity==Infinity' the program states that the line

```
 ((Math.pow(a, n)) + (Math.pow(b, n)) == (Math.pow(c, n)))
```

is correct